# multiple if/else statement is laravel not working for me

Tags: laravel

please help me out, i want to perform this conditional statement is one or two of this conditional statement will be through but none of the expression i provide will be save to database... Thanks

This are the function that i called

```
public function updateuserstage($userid){

    $user = User::where("user_id",$userid)->first();
    //get the stage bonus for this stage
    $stageBonus = StageBonus::where("user_id",$userid)- 
    where("stage",$user->stage)->first();
    //get the completion bonus

    $bonus = $this->completionbonus($user->stage);

    $directdownline = $this->loaduserdirectdownlines($userid);

    // $downlineright = $this- 
    loaduserdirectdownlines($directdownline[0]->user_id);

    // $downlineleft = $this- 
    loaduserdirectdownlines($directdownline[1]->user_id);


    $downlineright = $this- 
    loaduserdirectdownlinesrightleft($directdownline[0]->user_id);

    $downlineleft = $this- 
    loaduserdirectdownlinesrightleft($directdownline[1]->user_id);

    // matching bonus reward
    if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($directdownline[0]->boosted == 1) && 
    ($directdownline[1]->boosted == 1) && ($downlineright == 2) && 
    ($downlineleft == 2)){
        if (isset($bonus['point']))
            $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

        if (isset($bonus['ultimapv']))
            $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus- 
     point+$bonus['ultimapv'];

        if (isset($bonus['cash']))
            $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus->cash+$bonus['cash'];

     // direct downline reward
```

This function here return true when i log it outside loop but never save to database in here

```
    } else if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($directdownline[0]->boosted == 
    1) || ($directdownline[1]->boosted == 1)){
        if (isset($bonus['point']))
            $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

        if (isset($bonus['totalultimarefbonus']))
            $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus- 
    cash+$bonus['totalultimarefbonus'];

    } else if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($directdownline[0]->boosted == 
    1) || ($directdownline[1]->boosted == 0)){
        if (isset($bonus['point']))
            $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

        if (isset($bonus['ultimarefbonus']))
            $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus- 
    cash+$bonus['ultimarefbonus'];

    } else if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($directdownline[0]->boosted == 
    0) || ($directdownline[1]->boosted == 1)){
        if (isset($bonus['point']))
            $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

        if (isset($bonus['ultimarefbonus']))
            $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus- 
     >cash+$bonus['ultimarefbonus'];

    } else if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($downlineright[0]->boosted == 
    1) || ($downlineright[1]->boosted == 1) || ($downlineleft[0]- 
   >boosted == 1) || ($downlineleft[1]->boosted == 1)){

        if (isset($bonus['ultimarefbonuschild']))
            $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus- 
   >cash+$bonus['ultimarefbonuschild'];

    // referral reward for parent user if boosted
    } else if($user->boosted == 1){

        if (isset($bonus['refbonus']))
            $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus->cash+$bonus['refbonus'];   

    // referral reward for user that is not boosted
    } else if($user->boosted == 0){

        if (isset($bonus['point']))
            $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

        if (isset($bonus['refbonus']))
            $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus->cash+$bonus['refbonus'];
    }


    $stageBonus->completed = 1;
    $stageBonus->completed_on = Carbon::now();

    $stageBonus->save();
    //increase user stage
    $user->stage+= 1;
    $user->save();

    }

}
```

This is the function that will determine what to save in those expression

```
public function completionbonus($stage){
    switch($stage){
        case 1:
            return [ 'voucher'=>600, 'cash'=>5000, 'point'=>100, 'refbonus'=>2000, 'totalultimarefbonus'=>4000, 'ultimarefbonus'=>2000, 'ultimarefbonuschild'=>1500, 'ultimapv'=>700];
            break;
    }

}
```

This is the model

```
Schema::create('stage_bonuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->bigInteger('point')->default(0);
        $table->bigInteger('cash')->default(0);
        $table->date('date_entered')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
    });
```

Comment: where do you save to the database? It's not in the code provided.

Comment: Thanks have edit my question

Comment: Your problem is data is not saving right? is there any errors shown or not? can I see your user model too.

Comment: no error is showing

Comment: what is the error then??

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much i really appreciate your effort
Have actually got the answer the condition is returning two or true and if is returning two or more true it will not get save to database... Thanks